# Uploading file to client server

Tags: windows, cmd, ssl-certificate

I am trying to upload a file to client server with help of shell script facing below error in command prompt as well as in cygwin software.

curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Even after adding certificate.

Using Windows X OS.

can anyone suggest to solve this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.  For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question.  Otherwise it may be impossible to tell *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: As the previous comment mentions, the more details you provide, the easier it will be for the community to help you. For example as a start, it would be good to post the relevant code you are trying to use for the upload